how to make the caption showup without caption text in `lstlisting` environment?
I found that only the non-empty caption text make the caption appear in outputed file, even a sapce character \ . Here's an example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=C++,
  frame = t
}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  singlelinecheck = false
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\ }] %note the character '\ ' here!
  class MyClass
  {
    public:
        MyClass()
        {
            // Constructor
        }
        ~MyClass()
        {
            // Destructor
        }
  };
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}


well, when I delete the space character \  of caption = {\ }, the caption in the output file disppears:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=C++,
  frame = t
}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  singlelinecheck = false
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={}] % look here, nothing in caption
  class MyClass
  {
    public:
        MyClass()
        {
            // Constructor
        }
        ~MyClass()
        {
            // Destructor
        }
  };
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}


I want to know if there's some way to ouitput caption when the caption = {...} is invoked even nothing in the curly braces (caption = {}) just like float table or figure environment. Can anyone give me some clue ?

If you want that all your listings have a number, but possibly no caption text, you can set caption=\mbox{} in \lstset.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\lstset{
  language=C++,
  frame = t,
  caption=\mbox{},
  columns=fullflexible,
}

\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
  singlelinecheck = false
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
  class MyClass
  {
    public:
        MyClass()
        {
            // Constructor
        }
        ~MyClass()
        {
            // Destructor
        }
  };
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=This has a caption]
  class MyClass
  {
    public:
        MyClass()
        {
            // Constructor
        }
        ~MyClass()
        {
            // Destructor
        }
  };
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}


Notes.

I added columns=fullflexible, because proportional fonts used like monospaced make my eyes bleed.

The setting for caption is restricted to lstlisting captions.


